Can't run a MAUI app on macOS because the provisioning profile
I have my .NET8 MAUI that has already a version for iOS. I wanted to run the same project in macOS. I followed the process for the creation of the certificates from the Microsoft documentation.
At the end of the process, I downloaded the provisioning profile for the MacCatalyst. When I try to install the certificate

I get this error

Only Development Provisioning Profiles can be installed in System Settings. Production Provisioning Profiles are imported within Xcode.


So, I opened Xcode and downloaded it from my account all the certificates. When I run the application in Visual Studio for Mac, I get this error.

Error: Could not find any available provisioning profiles for LanguageInUse on MacCatalyst.

What did I miss?

I found info before about the same issue, create a new XCode project it will load the profile, start from this hint

Have you tried using a Development certificate?

Today, I restarted the process, creating again all the certificates and so on. I'll give you an update later. Thank you for your comment @LiqunShen-MSFT

Thanks for your response. Please let me know if you have any questions.
